# Cheap boost converter ripple.

Tags: power-supply, boost, charging, ripple

I'm trying to boost 12v to 19v(for charging laptop) with a cheap boost converter. But I noticed that I have some voltage ripple (See images). What can I do about this? And will it hurt my laptop charging circuit.

[image: The ripple is only about 400ns]

Comment: How should we know without knowing your boost converter, your Laptop's current draw, and its tolerance against ripple?

Comment: How do we know how you have expertly connected your o-scope ground connection? Is it a 5 volt/cm range?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure that the current draw is too relevant here. The picture was taken when there was no load applied. The ripple did not change under load. And for the tolerance, I'm not sure how I would know that.

Comment: @Andyaka I just connected scope ground to circuit ground. Not sure how else I would do it. And yes, it's 5v per division.

Comment: How short was your o-scope ground wire? If you connected probe pin and probe earth wire to the same point on ground (yes the same electrical point), what do you see?

Comment: @Andyaka My scope ground wire is connected to the probe, so about 5cm. Do you mean connecting probe and probe ground? Or connecting probe, probe ground and circuit ground?

Comment: @SamuelKlit the usual way to measure ripple is to use [this sort of thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OPgl.jpg) and probe directly across the output capacitor.

Comment: So the length of the ground wire has a big impact on what I measure?

Comment: Indeed. Show your measurement setup and watch Dave from eevblogs video on how to measure ripple.

Comment: I just remembered my scope actually came with one of the clips you mentioned @SteveG. When I measured it again it was the same thing. I didn't remove the other alligator ground clip because I couldn't get it off. But I'm not sure if that has an impact that it was dangling around.

Comment: Also need to know what voltages your laptop will tolerate. Some easy fixes for voltage ripple maybe capacitors though do test it under no load and full load. This will also affect your rise times if this is a concern. You could also potentially place a zener to bypass if laptop will not tolerate this voltage.

Comment: It does not seem to be ripple per see but more switching noise. The probe pig tail forms a loop which pollutes the measurement because of the noisy environment hence the good advice to remove it. Charging a laptop can be tricky: some laptops require a constant charging current (CC) while only constant voltage (CV) with short circuit protection for others. However, there are less CC types these days. Also, there must be some maximum current limit for safety which is difficult to implement in a boost converter.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks. I don't think I can remove the pig tail though. My probes are GTP-100A.

Comment: Connect probe and probe ground together at circuit ground and repeat measurement - what do you see?

Comment: Please check Figure 1 in this link http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4411821/Testing-a-power-supply---Noise--Part-2-- and simply do not connect the pigtail in your measurement. Use the ground metal barrel connecting to your output ground instead. Make sure the probe cord is away from the switching converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple 0.47uf capacitor solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing your circuit. There could be several reasons for this. But judging from the waveform it is entirely possible that you are experiencing the [negative impedance phenomena](http://www.powerelectronics.com/regulators/input-source-impedance-affects-dc-dc-converter-performance).

If this is the case, one solution is to increase the output capacitance of your boost converter and slow down the voltage regulation loop.

The other solution would be to add a series RL damper to the output of your boost converter, e.g. a 1000uF in series with a 10 Ohm resistor. From the point of view of the oscillation, the system will become more resistive and hence more stable.